# Does javascript forEach create a new execution context for each array item or only update the lexical environment of current execution context?

Tags: javascript

In the below code, is a new execution context created for each item in the array, or does the execution context stay the same and only it's lexical environment's environment record update?

The code does not throw an error, so I assume that a new scope (lexical environment) is created independent of the execution context but I'm not sure if I am right about that.

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3]

nums.forEach(num => {
  const foo = num
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special about the callbacks provided to standard library functions. They're still functions, and they're still called in the usual way functions are called.

> In the below code is a new execution context created for each item in the array...

Yes. Whenever you call a function (in this case, when `forEach` calls its callback), a new execution context is created.

> ...The code does not throw an error, so I assume that a new scope (lexical environment) is created independent of the execution context...

Not (in this case) as a separate thing from creating a new execution context, no. As part of the standard process of calling a function.

In contrast, consider a `for-of` loop:

```
for (const num of nums) {
    const foo = num
}
```

Here, there is no callback function to call; the body of the loop is just a block. But a new lexical environment object is created for each loop iteration, thanks to the way the semantics of block scope were defined. That means that, similar to the `forEach` callback, there is a new `foo` for every loop iteration, even though there's no function call needed. (This is very handy if you're creating event handlers or similar inside that block.) (If we'd used `var` instead, there wouldn't be a new one each time, the `var` would jump out of the block to the surrounding function scope or global scope, since `var` is not block-scoped. This is one reason I suggest never using `var` in new code.)

Comment: Ok thanks, I have another question related to this, I was inclined to think that only the environment record of the running execution context updates because of the way reduce works. What you are saying is an execution context is created each time a function is called, the only thing I am confused about is in `Array.prototype.reduce()`, how does a block scoped variable get returned and used in the next iteration?

Comment: @dbzx10299 - Via `return`. The `reduce` function takes the return value of the callback and then passes it to the callback again on the next iteration. It's not a single thing, it's a new parameter on each iteration, very much as though you'd done `let acc = 0; for (let n = 0; n < array.length; ++n) { acc = callback(acc, array[n]); }` (Note: That **isn't** an accurate implementation of `reduce`, it's just similar enough to hopefully illustrate the point.) To see that in action, write a `reduce` call where the callback doesn't return a value. :-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clear and concise answer. One last question just to drive the point home, can there be a running execution context whose lexical environment record updates more than once for the same execution context, i.e. independent of the running execution context?